# Pass a string to msoChartFieldFormula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to dynamically set the datalabel in a columnclustered chart. This works

```
.DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldFormula, "=""This Works""", 1
```

But passing a string to recreate "=""This Works""" fails with specified parameter has invalid value. Not much out there on msoChartFieldFormula any help is appreciated. I know I can set this to a cell, but for generating hundreds of charts this is too much to do by hand.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried to set the string to recreate `"=""This Works"""`.  (There is no real reason why `myString = "=""This Works"""` followed by `.DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldFormula, myString, 1` should fail if `.DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldFormula, "=""This Works""", 1` works.)

Comment: This is what I tried among the numerous variations of quotes. Dlbl = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "This Does not Work""""". I did find out that I can dynamically generate the reference to a cell and pass that as a string Dlbl = "=" & "'Sheet1'!$A$6", so I am trying to use index and match to determine a cell address to pass to the string.

Comment: `Dlbl = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "This Does not Work"""""` generates the string `=""This Does not Work""`, but you want to generate the string `="This Does not Work"`.  You can generate that by using `Dlbl = "=" & Chr(34) & "This Does not Work"""` or `Dlbl = "=" & Chr(34) & "This Does not Work" & Chr(34)` or `Dlbl = "=""" & "This Does not Work" & """"`or, more simply (in my opinion), `Dlbl = "=""This Does not Work"""`.

Comment: I tried many variations including your recommendation, but I think it has to do with msoChartFieldFormula not accepting a standard string? I have the cell reference working, so that will work for now, but I would like to know a correct answer, maybe I am wrong with forming my string, but I think I tried every combination to get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put some of the things you tried *into the question* and we can explain why they didn't work.  Most of your problems are probably because you have tried to put 2 double-quotation symbols into the string itself, but the double-double-quotation mark is only needed **within a string literal**.

Comment: It works. Been coding too long today. This format works MyString = "=" & Chr(34) & BA(5) & """" , BA(5) is the array variable that contains the string for the label. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend you be consistent and either use `MyString = "=" & """" & BA(5) & """"` or `MyString = "=" & Chr(34) & BA(5) & Chr(34)` but, yes, what you put in your comment will correctly generate a string containing something like `="sometext"`.